# Run Google Assistant SDK on boot (Raspbian)

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I am currently trying to get a cron job working, so that the google assistant starts automatically after boot. For that I created this cron job which executes on reboot.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/home/pi/Desktop:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

```
@Reboot lxterminal -t "Google Assistant" -e /bin/bash /home/pi/Desktop/init.sh
```

lxterminal will open a window with google assistant running within.
Here is my full cron job:

```
#!/bin/bash
            
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/home/pi/Desktop:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin     


source /home/pi/env/bin/activate
          
python3 /home/pi/assistant-sdk-python/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py
```

I already tried answers from similar problems and even specified the path variable for cron, but it still won't work for me. The script isn't the fault, when I execute it manually it runs fine.

Comment: try @reboot instead of the usual MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW format for a crontab

Comment: Yep it is just for testing @reboot doesn't work either

Comment: is your system running systemd ?

Comment: Its the standard raspbian so i think not

Comment: I think systemd is the default on rasbian...type  ls -la /sbin/init to see if it links to systemd, or just systemctl status. If you are using systemd, then everything might actually be easier - you just make a service file to run your script (or have systemd do everything)

Comment: It says /lib/systemd/systemd so yes positive for systemd

Comment: there are plenty of examples around of how to run a script at startup: here is a straightorward one that does exactly what you want: https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd

Comment: So, the service works but, lxterminal and x-terminal-emulator both get an error where they cannot open a display

Comment: so, this can be where systemd is a lot more useful than cron. you can either modify your script to check it has everything it needs before executing lxterminal etc., or alternatively add an After= (or Require=) to the [Unit] part of your service file so that  it only starts when whatever lxterminal etc. depend on have already started. (again you can google how to do this). There may already in fact be a service attached to the terminal proceses, check /etc/systemd/system to see what other services there are.

Comment: also, i don't know if your PATH statement helps. It is probably better to dispense with the script and have an ExecStartPre=source /home/pi/env/bin/activate followed by ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/assistant-sdk-python/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py

Comment: could you provide a link for the checking stuff?

Comment: i also need the terminal windows to be visible so one can interact with it and the lxterminal -e command only accepts one command so i guess this is the only way to di that.  I also checked and it does not seem like lxterminal has any services running

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/12731 - scratch that it doesn't work on latest versions. I'm guessing that then there is a systemd service that starts it up. You can simply create another start up service file to run lxterminal with ExecStart=/path/to/lxterminal/lxterminal -e

Comment: Still says unable to init server and cannot open display so there just seems to be a problem with lxterminal while executing from systemd or as a service

Comment: in [Unit] you can add the line After=network.target and in [Install] you should have WantedBy=multi-user.target then type systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: Bash is still unable to init server: connection denied and lxterminal still: cannot open display

Comment: Ah ok; see https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11072#:~:text=You%20cannot%20open%20a%20graphical,LXTerminal%20from%20the%20main%20menu. ....you may need to  run the command startx before lxterminal

Comment: Ok by my understanding i need to run an X Server with startx but now i am in a boot loop when i login, i guess something is running startx over and over again, as the pi user and it still does not work

Comment: Solved the boot loop, but i still dont know why it did not work, i mean afterall it is just a bash file to open a terminal and write something in it, that can't be that hard

Comment: yeah but there are daemons and services and things getting started up and sequences of events and so on. nothing's ever simple, but it really isnt that hard either. Your script should loop and sleep until whatever you need is running: that can be a simple as doing a ps | grep <whatever>. its not very often that you can just add something into the middle of a startup sequence, everything is very controlled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with cron, though I settled for using a systemd service instead.
What I didn't know was, that Lxterminal needed a initalized screen to work and due to the script running on boot it wasn't.
This is an easy fix. Either add an delay of 30 Seconds or other values, depending on your system, to the beginning of your script or simulate the display beeing initalized already with `export DISPLAY=:1`